# Rewrite A Filename To Another Filename Via .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I wanna change "announcements.php" to "blog.php" in the url. Individual article's are identified by id=x, such as"annoucements.php?id=1", which I will need it to say "blog.php?id=1".

I tried:

```
RewriteRule ^announcements.php ./blog.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^announcements\.php /blog.php [NC,L]
```

If you change the file name in the url, you do a redirection, not a rewrite.

Comment: No, a redirect isn't what I'm trying to do. It would give me a 404 error. The web application I use just makes it too complicated to go through the system and change "announcements.php" to "blog.php", especially when redoing it every time there is an update. I'm just wondering if there is a way to redo the URL appearance.